Reference request? Lévy's continuity theorem
I am trying to understand a proof that involves constructing a measure $\mu$ as a weak limit of measures $\mu_k$.
The author concludes the weak convergence as a consequence of Lévy's continuity theorem. I've looked this theorem up and it is stated for probability measures. The thing is, I am not seeing how the measures $\mu_k$ involved are of Probability. But this is not what I am here to ask. I suspect that this might not even be the case, because after the measure $\mu$ is constructed, the author goes out of his way to prove that $\mu$ is not the zero measure, which should be obvious if the measure was of Probability, as the theorem guarantees. This leads me to believe that there is some version of Levy's theorem for non-probability measures that I haven't been able to find. Is this the case? If so where could I find it?

You can find the proof sketch of Lévy's continuity theorem for finite measures on $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ in Ex. 21.3 p. 225 in Schilling's Measures, Integrals and Martingales. Given a sequence of finite measures, if the sequence of functions $\xi \mapsto \hat{\mu}_n(\xi)=\int e^{-i\xi \cdot x}d\mu_n$ converges pointwise to some $\xi \mapsto \phi(\xi)$ continuous at $\xi=0$ then there is a finite measure $\mu$ s.t. $\mu_n\to^{\textrm{w}}\mu$ and $\phi=\int e^{-i\xi \cdot x}d\mu$.
Note that it is not possible that $\mu_n$ are all probability measures and $\mu$ is not. $\mu$ must necessarily be a probability measure. Indeed, $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ is bounded and continuous, so $\mu_n\to^\textrm{w}\mu$ implies $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}^d)\to \mu(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and if $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}^d)=1$ for all $n$ then it must be that $\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)=1$.
